# Разработка эмулятора ретины для имитационного окна браузера на сайте

Tags: javascript, эмулятор

Добрый вечер! Нужны решения задачи, связанной с разработкой и интегрированием эмулятора ретины на сайт. Имеется имитационное окно браузера, расположенное на сайте, куда выводится результат верстки юзера (юзер решает задачу в редакторе кода ace.js). При изменении опций окна минибраузера (ретиновый экран активен/неактивен) надо, чтобы минибраузер реагировал на дескриторы ретины тега  и подгружал соответсвующие изображения. Есть мнение, что результаты можно добиться путем редактирования полифилла picturefill.js . Прошу помочь если не решением, то советом